# How to control Devise user_id value assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've got a simple Rails app the allows users to submit requests. I'm using Devise to register and then authenticate the users.

In Devise, user_id is an integer and Devise assigns the value of "1" to the first registered user, then "2" to the second and so on.

I want to control the value of user_id instead of Devise. The values will be essentially random 9 digit integers. The values will come from the user when they register--their employee ID.

How do you take control over user_id value assignment from Devise?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: Don't do that. Instead of this, use another column in your database like `custom_user_id` and create a random number and assign that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably want to create a new employee_id field. user_id is the primary key of the table which needs to be unique and is used heavily by active record for associations etc.

Comment: I understand, but why does the actual value itself matter?
Devise starts at one and increments by one by default. But it could start at 10 or 99999 and increment by 3s or whatever. As I understand primary keys, the value shouldn't matter at the time it's generated. But once it is generated it can't change.

Comment: It *could* do that, but if you are doing things like that with your primary key it might indicate that you are doing something strange. if you have an employee id field that has to interface with another system or db it seems really rigid to have that also act as a primary key

Comment: Looking in the db I see that the "id" column is "AUTOINCREMENT", so I'd have to turn that off as well. Honestly my primary motivation is that "id" is alrady being passed to one of my controllers and I'm a newb and hasving trouble getting a new field into this controller.

Comment: Turning off autoincrement would defeat the function of a primary key. I don't totally understand what you mean by getting a new field into your controller. strong_parameters thing maybe?